# python pypetter package github action never ending run

Tags: python, web-scraping, github-actions, github-actions-runners

[github action link](https://github.com/ninetynin/slcm_notifs/actions/runs/4722452451/jobs/8377047300)

this is an example workflow which runs a simple webscraping script

```
from pyppeteer import launch
# from instagrapi import Client 

async def main():
    # browser = await launch(headless=False)
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://slcm.manipal.edu')
    print(await page.title())
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

the thing is it takes so much time to run this file in github actions does anyone have any idea why?